# Web based voice chat application

Tags: web, open-source

I'm looking for a simple server-webclient voice chat software, but yet I only saw "[voxli](http://www.voxli.com/)" and it's down.

Is there any such software which could be run on a linux based server (raspberrypi actually)? I wanted a web based client because guys won't need to download another software, I hope this exists!

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: web-based is what will be difficult. Otherwise, [mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, but is there really nothing on that? If so, it's weird!

Answer (score 1):

[tawk.com](http://www.tawk.com) is a free and private, non-intrusive, WebRTC-based solution you might like very well. You can reserve your own room or create one at random. The technology behind it relies on desktop browsers such as Firefox or Chrome and sets up a peer-to-peer connection between the chat-ees *(if that's a word)*. In any case, it also works on late versions of Android.

You can even get notifications when someone attempts to join your room while you're not in it. You can do audio/video/file-transfers. They provide a simple copy/paste code-snippet for inserting a sort of *call-me* `tawk.com` button into any interface. You can likely even get your own url - mine is *tawk.com/mikeserv* for instance. It's pretty handy and completely browser based.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Client app for Chat, and behind the scene proper Chat Server.
Here's a list of Chat Servers:
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/